# Handling shortcut keys using javascripts

Tags: javascript

I've used a button with a shortcut key as 'Alt+r'..I've changed the value of the button using javascript(without reloading the jsp) based on some evaluations.. How to set the accesskey for the button with the new value as "Alt+n" inaide the same javascript function.Just like 'innerHtml' is used to change the value of the button, s there any way that i can change the shortcutkey for the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [accessKey](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_accesskey.asp) property:

```
document.getElementById("yourButtonId").accessKey = "n";
```

You cannot guarantee that it will be mapped to `Alt+N`, though, since [that depends on the browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key#Access_in_different_Browsers).

Comment: I'm sorry ,I should hav given a heads up to u guys before..I tried using the above mentioned statement but it didnt work..The browser that i'm using is IE8..Can u suggest some other way..

Comment: @user258387, can you elaborate? Does the previous access key (`Alt+R`) still work?

Comment: Sorry again.. I made typo errors while using the above statement.. Its workin fine aftr rectifyng it..Thank u..

Answer (score 0):

to use the alt key you will have to catch some events (keyup, keydown, depending on the technique you're using). This is quite unreliable on a number of platforms and browsers though. Here's some more information: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html and here is a demo of 2 different techniques: http://www.cross-browser.com/x/examples/shift_mode.php. Good luck!